# Duplicate number in an array in java giving wrong output

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, duplicates

Here I have sample java code which to count number of duplicate numbers in an array.

example:

I have array `A[]={3,4,5,3,4,3}` so I need the output

```
3 occurred 3 times
4 occurred 2 times 
5 occurred 1 time
```

How can I get this with my following program.

```java
public class testNumberCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] temp;
        System.out.println("Enter numbers Separated with comma(,)");
        String inputSrc = "";
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            inputSrc = sc.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        temp = inputSrc.split(",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
        int[] numberarray = new int[temp.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            numberarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < numberarray.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0, count = 0; k < numberarray.length; k++) {
                if (numberarray[j] == numberarray[k]) {
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println("number " + numberarray[k] + " Occured:" + count + " times.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here my wrong output is:

```
number 3 Occured:1 times.
number 4 Occured:1 times.
number 5 Occured:1 times.
number 3 Occured:2 times.
number 4 Occured:2 times.
number 3 Occured:3 times.
number 3 Occured:0 times.
number 4 Occured:1 times.
number 5 Occured:1 times.
number 3 Occured:1 times.
number 4 Occured:2 times.
number 3 Occured:2 times.
number 3 Occured:0 times.
number 4 Occured:0 times.
number 5 Occured:1 times.
number 3 Occured:1 times.
number 4 Occured:1 times.
number 3 Occured:1 times.
number 3 Occured:1 times.
number 4 Occured:1 times.
number 5 Occured:1 times.
number 3 Occured:2 times.
number 4 Occured:2 times.
number 3 Occured:3 times.
number 3 Occured:0 times.
number 4 Occured:1 times.
number 5 Occured:1 times.
number 3 Occured:1 times.
number 4 Occured:2 times.
number 3 Occured:2 times.
number 3 Occured:1 times.
number 4 Occured:1 times.
number 5 Occured:1 times.
number 3 Occured:2 times.
number 4 Occured:2 times.
number 3 Occured:3 times.
```

For this one I'm getting some wrong output, can anybody run and solve my problem.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: First thing to improve in your sample code: replace the first two thirds of it with `int[] numberArray = { 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3 };`. Then you can focus on the important bit which is going wrong. Now, what is your *actual* output?

Comment: Use Map instead of Array that need to resize.

Comment: @WundwinBorn,can you modify my code please.

Comment: @JonSkeet,I'm getting output as:

Comment: Don't put it in a comment - add it to the *question*. I've given you a suggestion for *improved* output, and a hint for how to go further.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently writing output on each iteration of the *inner* loop... which means you're getting much more output than you want. You want to print out the result once per iteration of the *outer* loop, which means bringing `count` into the scope of that loop too, and not using `k` in the output either. So here's a start:

```
class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       int[] numberarray = { 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3 };
       for (int j = 0; j < numberarray.length; j++) {
           int count = 0;
           for (int k = 0; k < numberarray.length; k++) {
               if (numberarray[j] == numberarray[k]) {
                   count++;
               }
           }
           System.out.println("Number " + numberarray[j]
                              + " occurred " + count + " times.");
       }
   }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Number 3 occurred 3 times.
Number 4 occurred 2 times.
Number 5 occurred 1 times.
Number 3 occurred 3 times.
Number 4 occurred 2 times.
Number 3 occurred 3 times.
```

Now, that's accurate - but includes duplicates. Think about how you can detect duplicates (think about the relationship between `j` and `k` when you've spotted that `numberarray[j] == numberarray[k]`).

An alternative is to go through the array *once*, maintaining a `Map<Integer, Integer>` where the key is the value in the array, and the value is the number of times you've seen that value... but you might want to get the brute force version working first.

Comment: Jon Skeet,Can you check my updated post,i mentioned coming output.

Comment: Jon Skeet,I'm learner i dont have that much idea can you please update your code using Map or something easy way.

Comment: @GangadharB: No, I'm suggesting that you don't go with the `Map` approach for the moment, but get your current approach working properly. Take the code I've written, and then think about how you can spot that you've already written the output for a number. I've given you a big hint in the post. (I'm assuming you're doing all of this as a school exercise, so it's important that you think and learn rather than just getting the whole answer from me directly.)

Comment: @GangadharB: Well that doesn't tell us anything about what you tried, what debugging you've done, what the output was, etc.